# MSSQL - Use Query results to find other details

Tags: php, sql-server

i have a query that i want to use the results from to search for other details in another table and display the results together

my initial query is to show all accounts and how many bookings have been made for the day specified

```
SELECT ACCOUNT, COUNT(ACCOUNT) Bookings 
FROM dbo.bookings 
WHERE DATEADDED = 101 
GROUP BY ACCOUNT
```

I then want to use the "ACCOUNT" which is a code to search for the name of the account in dbo.accounts.....

ACCOUNT is equal to CODE in dbo.accounts table and i need to get the NAME from this table

Comment: Hmmmmm, are you sure which database you're using? You've tagged a couple here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to join the two tables together, so:

```
SELECT a.NAME, b.ACCOUNT, COUNT(*) Bookings
FROM dbo.bookings b
INNER JOIN dbo.accounts a ON a.CODE = b.ACCOUNT
WHERE b.DATEADDED = 101
GROUP BY a.NAME, b.ACCOUNT
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking for something like this:

```
SELECT b.ACCOUNT
    ,a.NAME
    ,COUNT(ACCOUNT) Bookings
FROM dbo.bookings b
JOIN dbo.accounts a ON b.account = a.code
WHERE DATEADDED = 101
GROUP BY b.ACCOUNT
        ,a.NAME
```

Alternatively, you could use a CTE if you are using SQL Server:

```
WITH b(SELECT ACCOUNT, COUNT(ACCOUNT) Bookings 
        FROM dbo.bookings 
        WHERE DATEADDED = 101 
        GROUP BY ACCOUNT)

SELECT a.NAME
    ,b.*
FROM b
JOIN dbo.accounts a ON b.account = a.code;
```